# Has my internship offer expired? No response/call back from recruiter after offer letter was sent

Tags: job-offer, recruitment, internship

I'm a current CS student and was vying for an internship with Company A. I had interviews in December, and received a verbal offer by phone from my recruiter in the same month. Then, around last week, he sent a written offer letter.

In my stupidity, I told him that I was currently overseas and had limited Internet, but for him to let me know the next steps. I did not explicitly accept the offer letter, but I'm not sure if "next steps" could be interpreted as "I accepted". I did this because I was waiting on an offer from Company B (my top choice), but did not want to ask for an extension.

What's worse is I reread the letter and noticed that, at the bottom, it said to respond "within five days". I had read this five days after he sent the letter, so on the morning of the sixth day, I explained that this was an error on my part, and explicitly accepted.

I am a bit worried because he never responded to either of my emails yet; the former was sent five days ago and the follow-up two days ago. I also called him this afternoon to try to clear things but was taken to voicemail, with no follow-up call.

My plan is to attempt to call him on Monday morning, and maybe even the HR department if that is to no avail. Am I overreacting and reading too much into this? I'm overthinking a lot that he may have blocked/blacklisted me because of the initial email. I just wish I said "yes" in the first email and dealt with an offer from Company B after the fact, but it's too late for that unfortunately.

Comment: Entirely reasonable to call them and say "I know I was slow in responding, but I am still interested; did I get the position, or if it is still open can I ask to be considered for it again? Note that I said _call_; if time is important email is the wrong medium.

Comment: I did call my recruiter directly today, but I got sent to voicemail and he never called back. I am planning on calling him again on Monday. Would it be reasonable to call the HR department instead, if he doesn't get back to me?

Comment: @myGuy3 - I would stick with the individual you have already been communicating with.

Comment: Wow, that company waits for 2 months to send you a verbal offer. It may take them another 2 months to send you an official written offer. Maybe, they use the **Slow Motion** or **Speedy Snail** methodology. Just wait and see how they respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People can be busy with things, maybe he is on leave.  It is enough that you have emailed twice and that you are trying to contact him.

- But don't pester him.  Call him only once a day at most, for 2 or 3 days, tops.
- If you are being taken to voicemail, then leave him a voicemail.
- Do not go over his head, directly to HR. Absolutely no one likes that.

Comment: That makes sense and is reassuring. I’ll attempt to call him on Monday, and leave a voicemail if he doesn’t answer. I won’t attempt to contact him after that

Answer (score 1):

> Am I overreacting and reading too much into this?

Yes.

It is unlikely that the recruiter blocked/blacklisted you.

To me, if you call the recruiter once and leave a message on their voice mail, that would be enough. You can also write him an additional email just in case. Professional people will check their phone/email and respond to you ASAP.

So, let them respond on their own time frame.

I don't see the point of calling the same recruiter too many times.

**There are 2 possible scenarios:**

1. They intentionally ignore you because they find someone else. In this case, they will send you a rejection email later.
2. They will reply you later because they are too busy, or the boss is on vacation now. They may discuss the next step with you.

---

For now, you should focus more on company B, and apply for more jobs at other companies.